# MongoExport - add date to filename

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver, export-to-csv, mongoexport

Is there a way to append today's date formatted as "mm-dd-yyy" to a file name in a mongoexport command?

My command looks like this:  `mongoexport --username x --password y --host a1.mongolab.com --db mydb --collection Contacts --type=csv --fields "FirstName,LastName,EmailsAddress" --out "c:\test\out.csv"`

I want the file to be named as:  out_04-06-2016.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than the obvious of adding in a hardcoded date to your filename, you could do it as a batch file.

1) Create a text file with a .cmd extension.

2) add this code, save and then double click to run.

```
set mydate=!date:~10,4!!date:~7,2!!date:~4,2!
mongoexport --username x --password y --host a1.mongolab.com --db mydb --collection Contacts --type=csv --fields "FirstName,LastName,EmailsAddress" --out "c:\test\out_%mydate%.csv"
```